# Can I add iptables rule from the inside of a C Linux program only with capabilities or do I need necessarily root?

Tags: linux, iptables, root, c, capabilities

I need to add an iptables rule from the inside of a C Linux program.

How should I do? Do I need root privilege or can I just grant some capabilities?

I tried granting CAP_NET_RAW+iep and using popen(), system() and execve() to set iptables but it doesn't work.

It obviously works when I sudo but I would like not to grant root privilege.

Thank you.

Comment: Looking at [this](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-hacking-HOWTO.txt) (specifically `4.6.3` underneath "set") it seems to imply NET_ADMIN is the capability responsible for that. What happens when you give that capability to the `iptables` executable (`/sbin/iptables-multi-1.4.7` on my system) and try to run it as non-root?

Comment: But for the "can I just grant some capabilities" the answer is almost always "yes" for things like that. Unless you need it to be the "root" user for specifically for some reason, it's usually just a matter of figuring out what capability root has that your regular users don't in regards to the operation.

Comment: iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root)

Comment: I'm afraid it's something about inheritance since I'm not calling iptables directly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to grant root privilege to a user. you can edit your sudoers file and you can limit which commands a user can run via sudo. also, you can provide a NOPASSWD option in sudoers file.

```
MY_USER_NAME  ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/iptables
```

after editing your sudoers file MY_USER_NAME is able to run "sudo iptables" command. and can't run any other privilege needed commands.

use "visudo" command to edit your sudoers file.

Answer (score 1):

For iptables v1.8.4 (legacy) the following capabilities should allow you to run the `iptables` and `iptables-save/restore` commands:

```
setcap cap_dac_read_search,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw+ep /path/to/your/bin
```

You can test this by copying the `xtables-legacy-multi` binary and manually adding the capabilities above:

```
sudo cp /usr/sbin/xtables-legacy-multi ipt
chown ipt user:user # Some non root user
# Test a command
./ipt iptables -I INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
# Should see errors here...
# Update caps
sudo setcap cap_dac_read_search,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw+ep ipt
# Now test a rule
./ipt iptables -I INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
echo $?
# Should see a successful exit code of 0 for valid rules
```

An alternative is to use `libnftnl` [netfilter's netlink library](https://netfilter.org/projects/libnftnl/index.html), however the capabilities above would still apply (with the possible exception of the `cap_dac_read_search`).